# Fighting with dates and times

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, datetime, time

I've been fighting for hours with datetime values. I now have the date values working right, but the times are still giving me trouble. Consider the following:

```
Private _pickupDate As DateTime

Public Property PickupDate As DateTime
    Get
        Return _pickupDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
        _pickupDate = value
        txtPickupDate.Text = value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PickupTime As DateTime
    Get
        Return DateTime.Parse(ucPickupTime.Time)
    End Get
    Set(value As DateTime)
        ucPickupTime.Time = value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
    End Set
End Property
```

**Please Note:** ucPickupTime is a user control that consists of 3 DropDownLists (Hours, minutes, and seconds). It's `Time` property is a string that will always look like `HH:mm:ss`

Assume that I'm reading the datetime value `2012-10-26 16:00:00` from mysql.

When writing into the database, everything works smoothly, however, when I'm reading the time portion of the datetime, I'm getting back 04:00:00 (as opposed to 16:00:00) appearing in ucPickupTime.Time. Furthermore, when I read this into a gridview, it appears as 2012/10/26 04:00:00 PM

Obviously this is unacceptable as there's a big difference between 4 AM and 4PM

I've tried a number of ways to correct this, but just haven't been able to find the right one and I'm running out of ideas.

If anyone can suggest a way for me to keep the true time value (exactly as it is in the database) and put it into my control (or at least format it the way I want it), I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

** EDIT **
I've updated the code above to reflect latest changes. This now formats the data correctly, but when updating or inserting a record into the database, the values appear as follows:

> PickupDate | #12:00:00 AM# | Date
>   PickupTime | #10/4/2012 3:00:00 PM# | Date

What I've noticed looking closer at the data is that the date value used seems to always be the date on which the data was saved, not the date specified in txtPickupDate.Text

Comment: It looks like you are reading 4PM from your data which is the **same** as 16:00:00. How are you filling your gridview?

Comment: @MarkHall just from a data reader, no formatting whatsoever: `<asp:BoundField DataField="res_date" HeaderText="Date" />`

Comment: changed it to add `DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}"` and the gridview displays correctly not at least

Answer (score 1, accepted):

txtPickupDate.Text = value.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

Comment: Ideally, the getter should use Date.ParseExact too.

Comment: The date isn't what I'm struggling with here though, but this did give me an idea